# dplyr pipe: how to add a margin row calculating a total (like addmargins function - base)

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

My data:

```
 data <- data.frame(column1 = c("A","B","C","D"), column2 = c(4, NA, NA, 1))
```

My pipe:

```
 library (dplyr)
 data2 <- data %>%
          filter (grepl("A|B|D", column1))
```

My question:
How can I (simply) continue my pipe to add a row containing the total of the column2 (total = 5)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do:

```
data2 <- data %>%
  filter (grepl("A|B|D", column1)) %>%
  rbind(., data.frame(column1="Total", column2=sum(.$column2, na.rm=T)))

  column1 column2
1       A       4
2       B      NA
3       D       1
4   Total       5
```

Comment: It works fine but it's a bit long. I am looking for something more simple.

Comment: @Wilcar OK, good luck with that ;)